# Почему не отправляется фото aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Пытаюсь отправить сообщение + картинку. На пк все работало, а на сервере не пашет(

```
photo_lol = ['AgACAgIAAxkBAAJSWWNvU-FgJtkF3a2VDAb7ESBtt4GwAAJswzEbxuaBS0SRa-IywHblAQADAgADcwADKwQ']
await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo_lol[0], 'Привет')
```

выдает ошибку:

```
future: <Task finished name='Task-7' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=WrongFileIdentifier('Wrong file identifier/http url specified')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "main.py", line 142, in price
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo_lol[0],'Привет')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 561, in send_photo
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
```

Comment: Пишет что у вас неправильный файл айди, и выглядит он как-то неправильно

Comment: я этот id получил через тг, он должен работать(на пк все работало)

Comment: Wrong file identifier/http url specified - надо передавать http url. Ещё Ваши данные должны начинаться как-то так: [data:image/png;base64,] На чём Вы бот пишите, модуль какой?

Comment: Вы скорее всего отправляете тот файл айди которого этот бот не видел, потому он и говорит что хз что это такое

Comment: там без разницы, видел бот ид или нет. Эта информация должна подтягиваться через апи тг

Comment: Хах, увы но нет. Бот может отправить файл айди только того файла который он "видел"